# LESS and IE support(below 10)

Tags: css, less

it's my first time here  so i'm sorry if i make some mistakes.

I have a problem with LESS file being read by IE. 
It throws the following error:

> 'SyntaxError: Object doesn't support this property or method in test.less'

It's very nice special div with those words at the top of the page.
Not in the debug, there is nothing, it's clean.
All other browsers have no problem with this.

I try all day long and nothing. Now even i'm trying only with this LESS file: This is the test.less file.

```
body { margin: 0 auto; background-color:red; }
```

So nothing fancy, right. But still nothing. So i guess there is an issue that i'm not aware of. But what?

Here is my snip from the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="src/showcase/Presentation/Css/test.less" />    
    <script src="src/showcase/Presentation/Script/less.js"></script>
    <script src="src/showcase/Presentation/Script/main.js"></script>
```

By the way in IE 10 it works.

I would really appreciate a helpful hint.

Answer (score 7):

According to the website, LESS does not officially support any version of Internet Explorer.

- "LESS runs on the client-side (**modern browsers only**)." [[the LESS website]](http://lesscss.org)
- "IE9 is not officially supported – it may or may not work."  [[LESS author]](http://starikovs.com/2012/11/27/does-less-js-support-ie-9-at-least/)

I recommend compiling your `.less` files to CSS and referencing those files across all browsers. You can use [a tool such as SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) to monitor your `.less` files and automatically compile them when changes are detected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to inform you that the second link [LESS author] doesn't work anymore, it redirects me to a phishing website

Answer (score 0):

It can work if you use less version 1.3.0. You also can manage the less version using the if else

```
<!--[if (!IE)|(gt IE 8)]><!-->
  <script src="~/less-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
   <script src="~/less-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

More over do not use import css statement in your less file.

---

Note: It is true that less current version do not support old browsers like IE8 but these old less version do.